# Is there any way to show results of broom functions in a page?

Tags: r, broom

I was using functions form package `broom`. But the results span over multiple pages. For example, using `mtcars` data, I fitted a linear model with

```
model1 <- lm(mpg~. , data=mtcars) # mpg regressed on all other variables of dataset.
```

I want to see the regression results (like R-squared, AIC, etc.) using the`broom::glance` function, but the table showing the regression results is wider than the page width. Is there any way such that the remaining columns can be shown in the next rows? I tried `knitr::kable` also along with it, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: What about something like this: `glance(model1) %>% select(r.squared, AIC)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to save the output in .csv file

```
library(broom)

model1 <- lm(mpg~., data=mtcars)
tmp <- glance(model1)
#To have the result in the console
write.csv(tmp)
#To write the results in .csv file
write.csv(tmp, "lm_results.csv")
```

Comment: That's a fair idea, but I want to keep the results in an R markdown document to keep it reproducible. Writing csv file doesn't serve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see it in the console, you can do:

```
options(width=140)
glance(mdl)
```

or

```
data.frame(glance(mdl))
```